# Как правильно прочесть слово/символ?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, char, ввод

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a;
    printf("a:");
    scanf("%s", &a);
    printf("%s", a);
    return 0;
}
```

как написать правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В С++?

```
string s;
cout << "a: ";
cin >> s;
cout << s;
```

В С...

```
char a[100]; 
printf("a:");
scanf("%s", a);
// Но по-хорошему - scanf_s("%s", a, 100);
// или хотя бы scanf("%99s",a);
printf("%s", a);
```

P.S. Это если вы верно указали `%s`, т.е. читать слово. Если верно указано `char a;` — т.е. чтение одного *символа*, то просто замените все `%s` на `%c`...